# Handling Dangling Pointers in Go

Tags: pointers, go, dangling-pointer

I have been reading Rust and Go in parallel and I see subtle differences in how both these languages deal with dangling pointers and the problems it causes. For example, here is a version in Rust:

```rust
fn main() {
    let reference_to_nothing = dangle();
}

fn dangle() -> &String {
    let s = String::from("hello");

    &s
}
```

The above would error out saying that in the function `dangle`, `s` goes out of scope and I cannot return a reference to it! But in Go, this seems to be sort of allowed?

How is such a thing handled in Go? Is it easy to create dangling pointers in Go? If so what measures do I have to control them?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In Go, dangling pointers are not a thing, due to the way how [escape analysis](https://web.archive.org/web/20200414222520/http://www.agardner.me/golang/garbage/collection/gc/escape/analysis/2015/10/18/go-escape-analysis.html) works. Suppose you have a code like this:

```
func CreateUser(name string) *User {
    return &User{Name: name}
}
```

The compiler will understand that because the pointer can be accessed after the function exits, the structure should be allocated on heap. As [Effective Go](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#composite_literals) says:

> Note that, unlike in C, it's perfectly OK to return the address of a local variable; the storage associated with the variable survives after the function returns.